# Switching from ubuntu to ubuntu wayland system now lagging

Tags: 22.04, wayland

I switched via the login screen from ubuntu to ubuntu wayland. However now my system is lagging. My laptop is pretty powerful and im using 2 monitors. What could be the problem?

[image]

Comment: nvidia. Wayland may not always work well with the proprietary nvidia drivers.

Comment: I have the nvidia-driver-515 installed. Do you think updating to 525 will help?

Comment: I have no idea. I do not have nvidia.

Comment: same for me, problem eliminated.  in dmessg it wasKey repeat discarded, Wayland compositor doesn't seem to be processing events fast enough! in vlc, tools, messages, 2-debug mode it was ' 'main warning: picture is too late to be displayed (missing 73 ms)'  . I would rather have a smoother system than a better desktop. (pale blue task switcher background and white app title below, does not look good. on the normal ubuntu desktop I cannot get HDMI to output. so I cannot use that. I

Comment: n my software, additional drivers, no proprietary drivers are in use but I do have manually installed nvidia 535  (so no, i do not think 525 will help)